# 2d dynamic allocation

Tags: c, function, 2d, malloc, allocation

I want to allocate dynamic an array of chars. So i ve the above code

```
      void initialize(char **document_table, int size){

      int x, i, j, M;

      printf("how many words every line: ");  scanf("%d", &M);

     document_table = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
     for(x = 0; x < size; x ++) {
     document_table[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * M);
      }


     for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){

        scanf("%c",&document_table[i][j]);   
     }
      }
      }
```

but it seems that after the allocation of the memory the function stop working.

Comment: Your nested loops are using the same index variable `i`, and passing to `scanf` an address of the first element all the time.

Comment: In addition `N` is not defined or initialised. I think you might mean `M`. But if that is the case, you don't want `size` to be passed in as a function argument, you want it to be calculated based on what the user inputs?

Comment: xm iand j is wrong typing. But this was not the problem and in the place of N i ve got size. But it doesnt work after scand the first program stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `document_table = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);` should have `sizeof(char*)`, since a 2D array is an array of pointers to 1D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: `char** document_table` is itself passed by value. This means that calling code such as:

```
char** document_table = 0;
initialize(document_table,2);
/* document_table still 0 here */
```

will not initialise the passed parameter. Likely want to make the `document_table` the return value, or pass in its address.

Issue 2: `N` should be `size`?

Issue 3: `scanf("%c")` is inconsistent with the definition of `M` being "words". `%c` represents single characters. Also, the text `every line` implies line oriented input, but again this is not what the scanning looks for. If the document stores "words" then:

- a document is an array of lines
- a line is a array of words
- a word is an array of characters

So a document is actually a 3D array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate pointers in your array:

```
document_table = malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
```

Notice the `char*` in the sizeof() operator